# doc-view not working with emacs 25.2.1. (x86_64-w64-mingw32)

Tags: microsoft-windows, debugging, docview

I am definitely no newbie and I think I now followed every little advice I could find online, and after 2 days doc-view is still not working :-( (it works fine on my older laptop under windows 10)

On my new laptop (windows 10) I installed emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32), I installed 64-bit-Ghostscript, I put the line

```
(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program "C:\gs\gs9.20\bin")
```

in my .emacs, I checked the PATH, I copied the dlls zlib1.dll, libtiff-5.dll, libpng16-16.dll, gsdll64.dll in the emacs bin directory.

Yesterday, I installed cygwin64 and it worked partly, but doc-view was breaking from time to time when the document contains images, and I thought it could be a problem, when my ming32-based emacs uses some cygwin programming or dlls. But now, without cygwin, doc-view stopped to work.

I am not really familiar with emacs lisp, but evaluating

```
(image-type-available-p 'png)
```

yields `t`. Opening a pdf-File yield just the pdf source text. Forcing Emacs to enter `doc-view-mode` yields `Unable to render file. View extraced text instead?`

The ghostscript executables are in my PATH.

Any suggestions, how I can debug this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the answer is simple: the string constant in

```
 (setq doc-view-ghostscript-program "C:\gs\gs9.20\bin")
```

is wrong; the backslashes seem to be interpreted as special characters. And I forgot to specify the program. The correct statement is:

```
(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program "C:/gs/gs9.20/bin/gswin64c.exe")
```

Comment: If you have `C:/gs/gs9.20/bin/` in your `PATH`, it will suffice to say `(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program "gswin64c.exe")`.  If you want to use backslash as a directory separator, double it like ``\\``.  The function `expand-file-name` is also handy.  You can try `(setq doc-view-ghostscript-program (expand-file-name "C:\\gs\\gs9.20\\bin\\gswin64c.exe"))`